# Is assign statement in system verilog two way assignment ? If LHS is driven does RHS change?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Consider the assignment below

`assign A  = B;`

if I force A from testbench does B change ? If it does what happens in the conditional assignment scenario ?

`assign  A = S ? B : C;`

Answer (score 0):

No, a continuous assignment is unidirectional from the RHS to the LHS.

The only place a `force` ignores direction is with a port connection and both sides of the connection are nets/wires. The two nets get *collpased* into a single net, effectively eliminating the port.